# Is input() safe to use if you cast it as a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I've been experimenting with python 2.7's `input()` function and trying to find ways to exploit it. I know that by itself it's vulnerable to exploitation because you can input python expressions, which will then be evaluated. My question is, if you cast it as a string, ie:

```
str(input())
```

is it still vulnerable to these exploits? Does this make it completely safe?

As an example, given the following program, is there any way to exploit `input()` and make it output "RIGHT password"?

```
import random
inp = str(input("Enter the password: "))
password = random.randint(0, 100)
if inp == password:
    print "RIGHT password" 
else:
    print "WRONG password"
```

Comment: No. All your doing is casting the _result_ of `input()` to a string. Python still runs the code from `input()` before casting it to a string.

Comment: ObLink: [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> is there any way to exploit input() and make it output "RIGHT password"?

Yep:

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop>py -2 test.py
Enter the password: __import__('sys').stdout.write('RIGHT password') or exit(0)
RIGHT password
C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop>
```

"But that doesn't count because you're printing your own output and terminating early", you protest hypothetically. "Show me an example where the conditional actually executes".

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop>py -2 test.py
Enter the password: (1, globals().update({"random": type("", (object,), {"__init__": lambda self: setattr(self, "randint", lambda x,y: "1")})()}))[0]
RIGHT password

C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop>
```

"Ok, well, in a real application I wouldn't be using `random.randint` to determine the password. Show me an example where the conditional `inp == "hunter2":` passes"

```
import random
inp = str(input("Enter the password: "))
if inp == "hunter2":
    print "RIGHT password" 
else:
    print "WRONG password"
```

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop>py -2 test.py
Enter the password: __import__("re").search(r"if inp == \"(.*?)\"", open(__file__).read()).group(1)
RIGHT password
```

"That doesn't count because you read the file. Show me an example where you don't extract the password from the source code"

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop>py -2 test.py
Enter the password: type("", (str,), {"__str__": lambda self: self, "__eq__": lambda self, other: True})()
RIGHT password

C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop>
```

Comment: Why do some of  these exploits work in `python2` but not `python3`?

Comment: None of these exploits work in Python 3 when entering text into an `input` prompt, because unlike Python 2, Python 3 does not call `eval` on the text received. Or are you saying "why do some of these not work in Python 3 even if you explicitly eval the results with `inp = str(eval(input("Enter the password: ")))`?"? In that case, I just tried each one and they all still work except the first, which outputs `RIGHT passwordWRONG password`. Looks like in 3.X `sys.stdout.write` returns the number of characters written, which breaks the short-circuiting behavior of `or`.

Comment: Your first attempt made me laugh, I wouldn't have thought of that. Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

`input` has to process the string before it ever returns a value for `str` to turn *back* into a string. So no, "casting" does not make it safe.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific example: the string `[random.seed(1), random.randint(0, 100), random.seed(1)][1]` would always produce "RIGHT password".  It works by forcing the random number that will be generated to be one that's already been seen.

Answer (score 0):

try entering "exit()" as the string content , it will kill the interpreter. the casting to str doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

No. You are mistaken.

All you are doing is casting the the *result* of running the code in `input()` to a string. Python will still run the code in `input()`, regardless of whether you cast the return value to a string or not. Casting the result of `input()` to a string does not help its vulnerability:

```
>>> str(input('enter> ')) # Python will still run the code.
enter> 1 + 10 * 5
'51' 
>>>
```